# Recommended way to implement Push Notifications

Tags: android, iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am building an App for Android and iPhone. This app needs to receive notification for new messages in user's inbox. Being a total noob in app dev, I was wondering if any of you guys could suggest the best way to implement what I need here.

I have read up more on Android than iPhone so my understanding of latter may be wanting. Based on what I have read and understood, I believe that I will need to start a service when my app launches for the first time (or instruct the device to start the service every time the device starts or something). This service will then interface with a server to receive notifications and display them. Clicking on the notification will launch the app.

My options are

1. C2DM or APNS
2. Urban Airship
3. My own server using mostly idle TCP connection with client.

Depending upon the option I choose, my client side implementation as well as server side implementation changes.

What will you guys recommend? Is there any other way to do what I need done?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Building on jbat100 answer. The fact that Apple does not allow me to write my own server to communicate directly with my app for notifications means that APNS must be used. So option 3 is out altogether. This means we are left with either Urban Airship or interfacing directly with APNS and C2DM. Based on my research, the effort involved in both cases is comparable so it does not make sense to shell out 4-5K /mo extra just to support notification. So I plan to implement option 1. If any of you think otherwise, please leave comments below.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you can very easily just write your own APNS server. It is very easy, check this out https://github.com/matejkramny/apn-server

Answer (score 2):

They will have to be handled separately. In the case of iOS push notifications, you will have to go through the Apple Push Notification Service (Programming Guide [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)), they have a very specific protocol your server will have to conform to which is described in the [Provider Communication with Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1). Don't know about Android, it will probably be quite different, less centralized.

Comment: That answers part of my question. This means that APNS is the only way possible for iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

Building on jbat100 answer. The fact that Apple does not allow me to write my own server to communicate directly with my app for notifications means that APNS must be used. So option 3 is out altogether. This means we are left with either Urban Airship or interfacing directly with APNS and C2DM. Based on my research, the effort involved in both cases is comparable so it does not make sense to shell out 4-5K /mo extra just to support notification. So I plan to implement option 1. If any of you think otherwise, please leave comments below.

Answer (score 0):

C2DM would be the easiest perhaps. But, I think you can also try Urban Ship. Implementing your own server is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

My situation is very similar, and I released my Android app first, and am now working on an iOS app.  For Android, I implemented push notifications using C2DM, and I send the notifications from my Google App Engine (GAE) app.  C2DM basically requires sending HTTP messages to Google's server.  So, you send an HTTP POST to the URL https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send.

iOS however, requires a dedicated TCP connection on a proprietary port, and GAE environment doesn't allow any external protocol except HTTP over port 80.  So, I have researched a lot and Urban Airship seems to be the answer.  They provide an HTTP interface, which I can access from my GAE environment, and they convert that to the protocol that Apple's servers understand.  Their pricing seems confusing though - 1 million free notifications per month, and a tenth of a cent per notification after that.  That's bizzare because they're giving away $1000 free a month?  Very economically weird.  I'm considering trying them out, but I think the best high-volume alternative is to just use your own implementation, and deploy it on Amazon's AWS or buy other cheap 3rd party hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using C2DM will continue to work. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to the new version of C2DM, called Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM). See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information. Developers must use GCM for new development.

Answer (score 0):

I can't shed any light on the Android side of the equation, but I can tell you that I recently setup an incredibly simple Rails app on Heroku that sends push notifications to my iOS app via APNS.  I used the [houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston) gem and was receiving push notifications in my iOS app in less than 20 minutes from when I started the effort.